# include an image inside the sencha text field

Tags: javascript, image, forms, sencha-touch, textfield

I want to include an image (something like a '+' sign ) inside a textfield in sencha. Is it possible?

Here is what I need

[image]

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Hmm, this is a "system" button. Maybe, there's an option to create it with just sencha library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use technique for embedding an image into element with CSS:

- assign this image as background with no-repeat
- add padding on the corresponding side, where image is located

Comment: How do you create it?
Are styles applied in generated html?
You may edit your answer to show a part of your code.